# Change the status being shown when either one of the button has been selected in a table Django

Tags: python, html, django, button, html-table

May I know why is my status remain unchanged when either "approve" or "deny" button has been selected for that particular row? How can I pass the value that I change in views.py back to my html file in order to print out the status? Should I declare the Action field in models.py since action is just 2 buttons with name of approve and deny?

.html file

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table  id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="1.5px">
        <tr align="center">
            <th> Student ID </th>
            <th> Student Name </th>
            <th> Start Date </th>
            <th> End Date </th>
            <th> Action </th>
            <th> Status </th>
        </tr>
        {% for item in query_results %}
        <tr align="center">
            <td> {{item.studentID}} </td>
            <td> {{item.studentName}} </td>
            <td> {{item.startDate|date:'d-m-Y'}} </td>
            <td> {{item.endDate|date:'d-m-Y'}} </td>
            <td> <input type="submit" name="approve" id="approve" value="approve" > <input type="submit" name="deny" id="deny" value="deny" > </td>
            <td> 
            {% if not item.action %}
                    Pending
                 {% endif %}        
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</form>
```

When I try to print query_results in console, I can't see that the status has been changed.

views.py

```
def superltimesheet(request):
    query_results = Timesheet.objects.all()
    data={'query_results':query_results}
    supervisor = SuperLTimesheet.objects.all()[0]
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('approve'):
            supervisor.status = "approved"
            supervisor.save()
            return redirect('/hrfinance/superltimesheet/')
        elif request.POST.get('deny'):
            supervisor.status = "denied"
            supervisor.save()
            return redirect('/hrfinance/superltimesheet/')
    return render(request, 'hrfinance/supervisor_list_timesheet.html', data)
```

models.py

```
class SuperLTimesheet(models.Model):
    timesheet = models.ForeignKey(Timesheet, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    status = models.TextField("Status", default="pending", null=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use if conditional to catch post method like:

```
def superltimesheet(request):
    query_results = Timesheet.objects.all()
    data={'query_results':query_results}
    supervisor = SuperLTimesheet()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('approve'):
            supervisor.status = "approved"
            supervisor.save()
            return redirect('/hrfinance/superltimesheet/')
        elif request.POST.get('deny'):
            supervisor.status = "denied"
            supervisor.save()
            return redirect('/hrfinance/superltimesheet/')


    return render(request, 'hrfinance/supervisor_list_timesheet.html', data)
```

your mistake is in the var supervisor, it must be a single object something like `SuperLTimesheet.objects.get(pk=1)`, you should see url [dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#example)

Comment: is that the way i call in my html file for the {{item.status}} ?

Comment: TypeError at /hrfinance/superltimesheet/
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'QueryDict'      when i change my views.py to what u have up there, i got this error

Comment: view my edit, if you wanna see result change supervisor = SuperLTimesheet() to supervisor = SuperLTimesheet.objects.all()[0]

Comment: yes, must be replace by identifier of the object that you want to edit

Comment: srry, just delete the doc

Comment: how do i do that if i get the identifier of the object when the button of that row has been clicked ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153075/discussion-between-mauricio-cortazar-and-nobody).